# How to store cell contents from a UITableView in Xcode?

Tags: uitableview

I am seeking to be able to select a share name and purchase this share that I select. (i.e. Store the Name of the share in a portfolio) 
So far I have used the following code to select the name of the share:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

I would like the content within my table cell to display in a label and then have the option to store this in my portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework provides selection functionality out of the box, and will automatically save your selection.